# Node Sass version 6.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 in React.js

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app, node-sass, sass-loader

I tried to install sass-loader to compile scss, but it shows a version compatibility error. I downgrade the version and did so many things, but still shows the same issue.

React version- 17.0.2
node version- 16.2.0
npm version - 7.13.0

Package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "antd": "^4.16.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like Create React App, is it?

Comment: yeah, Its npx-create-react-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error seems to come from a version of `sass-loader` that doesn't handle `node-sass@6`.

It has been fixed in `sass-loader@11.1.0` by [this pull request](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/pull/947).

Also note that if you use `node@16`, you will have to use `node-sass@6` (see [node-sass version policy](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy))

To sum up: You can use `node-sass@6` given you also install a recent `sass-loader` version.

Comment: nothing worked. `yarn add sass-loader` then `yarn add node-sass@6 `/`yarn add node-sass` and still getting `Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0.`

Answer (score 22):

**`node-sass` is deprecated. Instead use `sass`.**

You can uninstall the old and install the new one.

```
npm uninstall node-sass

npm install sass
```

It works all the same, with no other changed needed.

**But if you want to use node-sass anyways** You can you can install the right version based on your node.js version as follows

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

You can choose your version number based on the following table, based on the node version you have installed, which you can check by the command `node --version`

[image: node-sass compatibility table]

I hope it helps you

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could try uninstalling `node-sass` and replacing it with `sass`. That did it for me.

```
npm un node-sass
npm i -D sass
```

Answer (score 1):

For the ones that uses yarn:

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add node-sass
```

if you want a specific node-sass version

```
yarn add node-sass@4.x.x
```

Answer (score 1):

Node Sass is also deprecated now so you can try uninstalling it by using this command

`npm uninstall node-sass`  and trying:

`npm install --save-dev sass`

this worked for me when I was having issues installing sass on a project using create  react app

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with node-sass, you can use the sass library instead.

```
npm i sass
```

You can also install it as a developer dependency if you prefer, it's even better practice.

```
npm -D i sass
```

Answer (score 0):

i uninstall node-sass and install dart-sass than my problem solved.it is about node-sass and sass-loader